# Am I able to use the same usb disk to boot and also make root/home partition to it?

Tags: linux, boot, partition, live-usb

When I try to boot new distro from a usb disk, then there are UEFI files to boot it. But during installation, I am asked to make partitions for root/home/swap and I have no more free hard disk space. So I would like to use the same usb with teh UEFI files. But once I want to save and write the disk, then:

```
Partitions on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform kernel of the change, probably they are in use
```

So I need to separate usb disk to partition and one to be bootable. Why cannot have one for all? (in other words, how to "inform" kernel of the changes - there should be no problem, when there are separate partition for `/`, `/home` `UEFI` etc.) or?

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the message. Just boot the system again. Then you can select the partitions you just created.

Comment: What does it says then? I thought I cannot have bootable usb with root directory

Comment: The message is quite clear. There was a problem with the kernel recognizing the partition table change. After a reboot that problem cannot occur any more.

Comment: Not that clear. The partition manager has deleted my UEFI files (because of request to make *new* partition for the root), and therefor I cannot boot it again, because the usb is messed up. I have to delete all partition, copy the iso file there, make new partition manually and that new pertition use in boot to make it root. That is not that trivial